# How to avoid Pandas throwing a SettingCopyWarning when transforming a subset of a series?

Tags: python, pandas

```
mask = ~df.bar.isna()
df.bar.loc[mask] = df.bar.loc[mask].map(f)
```

This sets off a SettingCopyWarning, though I am using `loc`.

I am aware of `df.mask`, but this will not work either as the column contains missing values that throw errors when the mapping function is applied to it .

Comment: What about modifying `f` so that it returns `NaN` when the input is `NaN`? This way you don't need the mask at all.

Comment: Do `df.loc[mask, "bar"]` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You get SettingCopyWarning because Pandas cannot be sure if you want to manipulate dataframe via a reference, or if you want to manipulate a copy of the dataframe. So try to add .copy() at the end of the second line and see if the warning goes away. Sometimes the cause of the warning is actually in the code somewhere a few lines before where you get the it.